# Ant script to fetch property value from another property file

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I have 2 properties files as below
a.properties has list of property names
b.proprties has list of its corresponding values

## a.properties

Application=

ApplicationID=

BU=

## b.properties

ACCSRV

ACCSRV

BT

I am looking for ant script which can give me final properties file with out out as below:

Final.properties:

Application=ACCSRV

ApplicationID=ACCSRV

BU=BT

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an external tool for this. If you can depend on unix tools, you can use the `paste` command (see `man paste`) and run it from ant using the `exec` task. If not, you can either

- write the tool in java, then use tasks `javac` and `java` to compile and run it from ant
- or use the `script` task to embed the tool in your ant script using some scripting language